# How do I fix a JavaScript error in a UNITY 3D project involving a System.IO.File member function?

Tags: unity-game-engine, .net, unityscript

I've got a function here that stores the coordinates of a chunk. It seems fine but the console gives me this error:

```
BCE0019: 'WriteLine' is not a member of 'System.IO.StreamReader'
```

If you have any idea how to fix this, I greatly appreciate it.

```
function writeChunks(fileName : String, xco : int, yco : int, zco : int) {
    var sr = System.IO.File.OpenText(fileName);
    sr.WriteLine("Chunk ("
                    + xco + ", " 
                    + yco + ", " 
                    + zco + ")");
    sr.Close();
}
```

**UPDATE 1**
This code:

```
 function writeChunks(fileName : String, xco : int, yco : int, zco : int) {
    var sr = System.IO.File.OpenText(fileName);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:/youfilename.txt", "Chunk ("
                + xco + ", " 
                + yco + ", " 
                + zco + ")");
    sr.Close();
    }
```

Gives me this error:

```
    DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "C:\Reactor Games\chunks.txt".
System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:292)
System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path, Boolean append, System.Text.Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/StreamWriter.cs:124)
System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path, Boolean append)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamWriter:.ctor (string,bool)
System.IO.File.CreateText (System.String path) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:159)
infiniteTerrain+$saveLoadedChunk$5+$.MoveNext () (at Assets/Script/infiniteTerrain.js:61)
```

**UPDATE 2**
This code:

```
function writeChunks(fileName : String, xco : int, yco : int, zco : int) {
    var sw = new StreamWriter("fileName"); 
    sw.WriteLine("Chunk ("
                + xco + ", " 
                + yco + ", " 
                + zco + ")");  
    sw.Close();
}
```

Gives me this error:

```
BCE0005: Unknown identifier: 'StreamWriter'.
```

Comment: Nothing yet, I have no clue what it can be :(

Comment: Upvoted your question tho.. so more people see it :-)

Comment: Would test and try fixes to problem, but won't be able to use Unity 3d library till after 8:00.  Voted up though as useful

Comment: @user3722399 DirectoryNotFoundException means that you need that directory. Create a directory called Reactor Games.

Comment: @user3722399 var sw = new StreamWriter("fileName"); should be var sw : StreamWriter = new StreamWriter(filepathIncludingFileName);

Comment: Note that UnityScript is different from Javascript. http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=UnityScript_versus_JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can add a C# class for your convenience and then simply you can call this. But it seems like you can also use this with JavaScript:

Also make sure that your directory exists:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filepathIncludingFileName, "Chunk ("
                + xco + ", " 
                + yco + ", " 
                + zco + ")");
```

I also checked other places some people are mentioning that you can just use StreamWriter class on JavaScript part:

```
var sw : StreamWriter = new StreamWriter(filepathIncludingFileName);
sw.WriteLine("Line to write");
sw.WriteLine("Another Line");
sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find this info on Unity3D scripting API documentation. You should use it with caution.

Comment: DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "C:\Reactor Games\chunks.txt".

Comment: It gives me an error that doesn't fit in this comment, i'l post it in my orignial post